# Why I cannot type a `list` parameter in a class with an existing `list` method

Tags: python, python-typing, python-3.10

I'm working with Python 3.10 and I have this class (which I have simplified):

```py
class Greetings:
    def list(self) -> list[str]:
        return ['ab', 'cd']

    def hello(self, names: list[str]) -> None:
        for name in names:
            print("Hello", name)
```

While testing it, I got this error:

```
... in Greetings
    def hello(self, names: list[str]) -> None:
E   TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable` error.
```

I know that the issue comes from my `list` method, which Python is trying to use in the typing of the `names` parameter. But I don't understand why this is happening or if it an issue with Python language. It is suppose that starting with Python 3.10 I can use `list` as typing instead of importing `List` from the `typing` module.

Any guess?

Comment: After `def list`, the name `list` refers to that `def list`.

Comment: you should avoid to name functions after wordings that are used in the python syntax

Comment: Code editor highlight reserved words

Comment: @GillesQuénot `list` is not reserved, though. It is just an identifier.

Comment: @MrIrrelevant `list` has no special *syntactic* meaning.

Comment: `class` statements are a bit weird. In the *end*, `Greetings.list` does not shadow the built-in `list`. But while the body of the `class` statement is being constructed, the new definition of `list` *does* shadow the built-in inside this temporary namespace.

Comment: This is proof positive that using built-in function names for other purposes is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you define `def list`, the name `list` inside your `class` block refers to that `def list` method. You've shadowed the name. You can work around this by aliasing `list`, or by using [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

```
import builtins

class Greetings:
    ...

    def hello(self, names: builtins.list[str]) -> None:
        ...
```